# MvvmCross not run in VS2013 and iOS 7

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mvvmcross

I'm working with MvvmCross beta 2 and VS2013. When I want to run the application I get an error "device not selected". The problem is that in the Tool Bar there are not device to choose but the IOS Host server is connected.

Please any idea how can I solve this problem ????

Comment: Are you getting a grayed-out box or the text "No Devices Attached"? What happens if you click the "Refresh build server info" button on the iOS toolbar?

Comment: You need to also make sure that the iOS project is set as the startup project.